# Header within a div within an anchor tag

Tags: seo

Me and a fellow webdeveloper are having a discussion about whether or not this is SEO-friendly. I think it's okay to have an anchor `<a>` tag wrapped around a div. As it's [perfectly valid in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032/2363481).

However, he says it's bad for SEO. As the `<h1>` tag will lose value in terms of SEO.

**The HTML:**

```
<a href="/link">
    <div>
        <h1>Header </h1>
        <img />
        <p>Some test</p>
        <span>SPAN ACTING LIKE A LINK HERE</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Does the `<h1>` lose value cause of this? We want the entire div to be clickable (for user experience) but don't want to make the `<h1>` lose value in terms of SEO.

Comment: Maybe this helps you and your friend to end the discussion : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/anchor-tag-inside-h1-or-h1-inside-achor-tag-which-is-better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, they're both the same.

As HTML5 does allow block-level links.

If your markup is valid, you do not lose any SEO value. More important is actually the quality of your link and text within.